# ImageMagick.NET.Web UrlResolver

Tags: c#, imagemagick

I'm trying to use ImageMagick.Net.Web at my Web Application but I'm stuck at the Configuration level in the Web.Config.

They use a UrlResolver in the documentation as

```
<magick.net.web cacheDirectory="c:\ImageCache\">
    <urlResolvers>
        <urlResolver type="YourLibrary.UrlResolver, YourLibrary" />
    </urlResolvers>
</magick.net.web>
```

and I don't understand how to define one, What can I do ?

Comment: Contact the developer of Magick.Net at http://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewforum.php?f=27

Comment: Great, Thank you.